# Very slow download speeds with yum install

Tags: fedora, yum, performance

On Fedora, I don't know why but every time I type in `sudo yum install [package]`, it gets me to this:
`Fedora 27 - i386    0% [                 ]  70 kB/s | 512 kB     12:47 ETA`

This is way far from what I expected. Why am I getting this?

Comment: Is it a progress meter of some sort, and you don’t want it? Or are the values *in* the output drastically different from what you expect?

Comment: Yeah it is a progress meter. I don't know what it is but it runs **very** slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly have a problem with the mirror used by `dnf`.

You can change your current mirror to one of the mirror [listed here](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/mirrormanager/mirrors/Fedora/27/x86_64).

As seen [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1035780/how-can-i-use-a-specific-mirror-server-in-fedora) :

> There are multiple options, you can hard code  it (`/etc/yum.repos.d/fedora.repo`) or using `fastmirror`.
>
> In order to use `fastmirror` you must first activate it:
>
> in `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf` add `fastestmirror=true` then using this
>   command `dnf config-manager --add-repo` add the mirror you want to
>   use, you can add multiple mirrors and the fastest one will be used.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> sudo dnf config-manager --add-repo http://ftp.byfly.by/pub/fedoraproject.org/linux/releases/23/Everything/x86_64/os/
> ```
>
> You must use the path `/linux/releases/23/Everything/x86_64/os/` for
>   fedora 23 releases and for fedora 23 updates
>   `/linux/updates/23/x86_64/` otherwise will not work.

Adapt this to your version of Fedora and you should see a big improvement.